# Can I achieve a higher resolution with an external monitor for my mac?

Tags: graphics-card, display, macbook, resolution, external-display

I have an old ATI Radeon X1600 128 MB graphic card with my late 2006 MacBookPro model. The system preference display only a 1440 x 900 resolution and all documentations I found say the same.

My question is, if it is possible to achieve a higher resolution (HD) if I connect an external monitor with a possible higher resolution? Is the graphic card able to handle that or other words is this a graphic card issue at all?

My Mac is that old, that the technical specifications only reveal in the google
[cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:30JXdQVUoVoJ:support.apple.com/kb/SP24%20ATI%20Radeon%20X1600%20128%20MB%20graphic%20resolution%20output&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=safari).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a graphic card issue.The screen and the external monitor is supported individually. The DVI or the DVI to VGA adaptor both support the resolution up to 1920*1080. Find a DVI Cable, connect, and set the resolution in the SYSTEM PREFERENCE/DISPLAY.